# How to drag/drop element from box 1 to box 2 with jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Code is like this :

HTML :

```
<div class="content">
    box 1 (Customer)
    <ol class='example limited_drop_targets default vertical'>
      <li>Valentino Rossi<ol></ol></li>
      <li>David Beckham<ol></ol></li>
      <li>Eden Hazard<ol></ol></li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="content">
    box 2 (Room Type)
    <ol class='example limited_drop_targets default vertical'>
      <li>Single Room<ol></ol></li>
      <li>Double Room<ol></ol></li>
      <li>Family Room<ol></ol></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
  $(function  () {
          $("ol.example").sortable();
        });
```

Demo/complete code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/x0q81hfq/

I take from here : https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Drag/drop element from box 1 to box 2 not working

I look for the code in the documentation does not exist

How to drag/drop element from box 1 to box 2 with jquery sortable?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first visit the examples page for the plugin and see if we can find any documentation that helps explain if the the plugin supports the functionality you are looking for.

[After a quick look we fine can pass in a "group" which accepts class so you're code changes like so:](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#connected)

```
$(function() {
  $("ol.example").sortable({
    group: '.example'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask again. I want to make like this : http://imgur.com/wIFwON3. So,I would like to add some conditions. 
Customers can only drag in room type. While room type can not drag to the customer. whether it can be done? I have tried but did not succeed.

Comment: I don't believe you have given it a try. The examples below the one I used have various examples and one of them actually matches very closely to your imgur picture. please check again: https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#connected

Comment: I tried it like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/vs4zggjf/.
I added a class `simple_with_no_drag`. But it's not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them to the same group:

```
$(function() {
    $("ol.example").sortable({
        group: "example"
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/pw6rs8t1/1/

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask again. I want to make like this : imgur.com/wIFwON3. So,I would like to add some conditions. Customers can only drag in room type. While room type can not drag to the customer. whether it can be done? I have tried but did not succeed.